# cannot setup apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi and python 3.3?

Tags: flask, mod-wsgi

This is error log when i'm trying to setup with Python 3.3, Apache 2.2 and use mod_wsgi-3.4.ap22.win32-py3.3.zip at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=4940): Target WSGI script 'C:/www/h.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=4940): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/www/h.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\Lib\\pkgutil.py", line 504, in find_loader\r
     return importlib.find_loader(fullname, path)\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\Lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 64, in find_loader\r
     loader = sys.modules[name].__loader__\r
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__loader__'\r
 \r
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:\r
 \r
 Traceback (most recent call last):\r
   File "C:/www/h.wsgi", line 5, in <module>\r
     application = Flask(__name__)\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 331, in __init__\r
     instance_path = self.auto_find_instance_path()\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 622, in auto_find_instance_path\r
     prefix, package_path = find_package(self.import_name)\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\helpers.py", line 661, in find_package\r
     loader = pkgutil.get_loader(root_mod_name)\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\Lib\\pkgutil.py", line 482, in get_loader\r
     return find_loader(fullname)\r
   File "C:\\Python33\\Lib\\pkgutil.py", line 510, in find_loader\r
     raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex\r
 ImportError: Error while finding loader for '_mod_wsgi_293471048e599ca28a13db229cd884c8' (<class 'AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute '__loader__')\r
```

and Browser show "Internal Server Error".

I don't know why because when i'm trying to setup with Python 2.7, Apache 2.2 and mod_wsgi-3.4.ap22.win32-py2.7.zip, it's OK

Somebody help me, thank so much!

P.s:

httpd.conf settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName webmaster@localhost
        WSGIScriptAlias / C:/www/h.wsgi
        <Directory "C:/www">
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and my app

```
from flask import Flask

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

it's work okay when i change to python 2.7

Comment: FWIW I was able to fix this by using a separate file and importing the application into it:

    wsgi.py:
    from my_app import app as application

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest asking about this on the #pocoo IRC channel:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/community/irc/

as that is where the Flask developers are. Flask appears dependent on the __loader__ attribute of the module under Python 3.3, but mod_wsgi doesn't currently add one. It is possible Apache/mod_wsgi needs to start adding one due to how the new module importer works, but also not sure if Flask should be tolerant of it not existing.

Provides any details back here.

Comment: ok, thanks you Graham Dumpleton, i will provide any details back here

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and it seems to be a problem related to Python 3.3 as the following patch indicates:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-checkins/2014-March/128573.html

Updating to Python 3.4 seems to be an option. I also found this workaround, which seems to work for now:
http://librelist.com/browser//flask/2013/9/18/problem-debugging-flask-under-python-3-3/